# Python script only scrapes one item (Classified page)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

## Python Scraper brings only 1 item...

I'm relatively new to python and well I made a script to scrap one of my country's classified page. So far the script only seems to be able to grab only one item which really is driving me nuts because I've been trying to fix it for a week now and well I don't really know anyone that can help. Id appreciate it if anyone could take a look and try to explain me what exactly am I doing wrong here.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'http://www.clasificadosonline.com/UDMiscListingID.asp?MiscCat=75'

# opening ip connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#HTML PARSER
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html5lib") #se cambio de "html.parser" a "html5lib por que jodia el closing form tag"

containers = page_soup.findAll("form",{"name":"listing"})

#testing variables
tags = containers[0].findAll("a", {"class":"Tahoma16Blacknounder"})
tagx = tags[0].text.strip()

filename = "products.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "names, prices, city, product_condition\n"

f.write(headers)

for container in containers:
#holds the names of the classifieds
names_container = container.findAll("a", {"class":"Tahoma16Blacknounder"})
names = names_container[0].text.strip() # comment here later

#the span class"Tahoma14BrownNound" seems to hold the prices
#container.findAll("span", {"class":"Tahoma14BrownNound"})
#the span class
prices_container = container.findAll("span", {"class":"Tahoma14BrownNound"})
prices = prices_container[0].text # comment here later

#holds the city of use of the products
city_container = container.findAll("font", {"class":"tahoma14hbluenoUnder"})
city = city_container[0].text.strip() # comment here later

#holds the states of use of the products
product_condition_container = container.findAll("span", {"class":"style14 style15 style16"})
product_condition = product_condition_container[0].text # comment here later

print("names: " + names)
print("prices: " + prices)
print("city: " + city)
print("product_condition: " + product_condition)

f.write(names.replace(",", "|") + "," + prices + "," + city + "," + product_condition + "\n")

f.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I look at the site structure and you're missing the parsing of the table after the form.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'http://www.clasificadosonline.com/UDMiscListingID.asp?MiscCat=75'

# opening ip connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#HTML PARSER
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html5lib") #se cambio de "html.parser" a "html5lib por que jodia el closing form tag"

containers = page_soup.findAll("form",{"name":"listing"})

#testing variables
tags = containers[0].findAll("a", {"class":"Tahoma16Blacknounder"})
tagx = tags[0].text.strip()

filename = "products.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "names, prices, city, product_condition\n"

f.write(headers)

tr = containers[0].findAll('tr', {"valign":"middle"})

for container in tr:

if len(container.findAll("a", {"class":"Tahoma16Blacknounder"})) > 0:
    #holds the names of the classifieds
    names_container = container.findAll("a", {"class":"Tahoma16Blacknounder"})
    names = names_container[0].text.strip() # comment here later

    #the span class"Tahoma14BrownNound" seems to hold the prices
    #container.findAll("span", {"class":"Tahoma14BrownNound"})
    #the span class
    prices_container = container.findAll("span", {"class":"Tahoma14BrownNound"})
    prices = prices_container[0].text if len(prices_container) > 0 else ''

    #holds the city of use of the products
    city_container = container.findAll("font", {"class":"tahoma14hbluenoUnder"})
    city = city_container[0].text.strip() # comment here later

    #holds the states of use of the products
    product_condition_container = container.findAll("span", {"class":"style14 style15 style16"})
    product_condition = product_condition_container[0].text # comment here later

    print("names: " + names)
    print("prices: " + prices)
    print("city: " + city)
    print("product_condition: " + product_condition)

f.write(names.replace(",", "|") + "," + prices + "," + city + "," + product_condition + "\n")

f.close()
```